# C++ array of objects. One element to access method of another element in array

Tags: c++, arrays, object

I have array of objects

```
MyClass MyArr[10];
```

In method of one element of array `( MyArr[j] )` I need to access to method of another element in this array `( MyArr[i].Method2(arg) )`.

How I Can do this?

Access from one element of array to another element of array?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What is `MyClass`? Why are the instances in an array?

Comment: mo details about application: MyArr - is the global storage of measured and calculated values in reality his consist 10 000 elements. Measured part of elements paken his parameters from ethernet exchange (for example 1, 2,3, 10,25 element) in non determinated siquence and time periods, calculeted elements takes his parameters from measured elements (10-th element takes parametersa from 1-st and 2-nd elements parameters). Indexes of measured and calculated elements are configured of user. Parameters of all elements of array are stored in database asichronous in separated thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's lots of ways. Some are:

- make `MyArr` a static variable of the `MyClass` class
- pass `MyArr[i]` as a parameter to the method call on `MyArr[j]`
- construct each object passing in a pointer or reference to the other instance

Comment: In real i-th element need access to several elements of array (for example 1,2 ,5 for 9-th element).

Comment: That would suggest going with the first option: every element has access to the class' static variables.

Comment: @Neuronet: yep, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

You can either pass the array to each object, or you might find a linked list worth trying

Comment: MyArr is a global static array. And created on compilation stage. In your way we need inicialise parameter of array elements in loop on start of application. Is there another way?